# How to unit test .net automatic validation?

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit.net, .net-8.0

Ho Ho Community!

Curiosity, we start to migrate to .net 8.0 and discovered that .net is automatically validate missing parameters.

Here an example of a response from POST https://localhost/devices/activate

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "deviceKey": [
            "The deviceKey field is required."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-1d79adff75ce5947168a526dac7bdb70-4b612cd077628f9e-00"
}
```

1. When this validation occur?
2. I am surprised, usually, we were doing an unit test to validate that behavior and now it seems we need an integration test to trigger this response by calling the end-point? Is there any other way to get that response in the scope of an unit test, without running the application?

Thank you!

Comment: Finally, we used `builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o => o.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);` to be able to use unit test to validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[ApiController]` attribute makes model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response,you could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#apicontroller-attribute) related

If you debug with an invalid model,you would get the automatic response without getting into the controller at all, and when  unit testing controller logic, only the contents of a single action are tested, not the behavior of its dependencies or of the framework itself.

If you want to ensure   app's components function correctly at a level that includes the app's supporting infrastructure,you should try with integration test